# Is there any way to use something like List<MyClass>.class?

Tags: java, spring, openapi

I'm using SpringBoot with OpenAPI and SwaggerUI to implement a rest api. I want to annotate a `@GetMapping` method with `@ApiResponses` to provide the schema of the response, but I'm struggling with the parameter `implementation` of `@Schema`. The return type of my method is `List<ScanDTO>`, so I tried the following:

```java
@ApiResponses( value = {
            @ApiResponse(content = {@Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = List<ScanDTO>.class))})
    })
```

But this doesn't work. Things like `ScanDTO.class` would work. The `implementation` argument is of type `Class<?>`.

My workaround would be to create a wrapper class like the following:

```java
public interface ScanDTOList extends List<ScanDTO> {
}
```

and use it. It seems to be working, but I think I wont need that additional class in the future, so I am wondering, if there is any way to get this working without this workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using ArraySchema should solve this for you

```
@ApiResponse(
    content = {@Content(
        array = @ArraySchema(schema = @Schema(implementation = ScanDTO.class))
    )}
)
```